# AppEngine: how do cursors work?

Tags: python

i have the following code

```
def get(self):
    date = datetime.date.today()
    loc_query = Location.all()

    last_cursor = memcache.get('location_cursor')
    if last_cursor: loc_query.with_cursor(last_cursor)
    loc_result = loc_query.fetch(1)

    for loc in loc_result:
        self.record(loc, date)
        taskqueue.add(
            url='/task/query/simplegeo',
            params={'date':date, 'locid':loc.key().id()}
        )

    if len(loc_result):
        memcache.add('location_cursor', loc_query.cursor())
        taskqueue.add(url='/task/count/', method='GET')
    else:
        memcache.add('location_cursor', None)
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong, but i am getting the same cursor which is not the effect i wanted. why isn't the cursor moving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misusing `memcache.add`, which is documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions.html) as:

> Sets a key's value, if and only if the
>   item is not already in memcache.

So you're never storing any cursor *different* from the first one.  Use `memcache.set` instead, which

> Sets a key's value, regardless of
>   previous contents in cache.

Note that this has nothing to do with cursors -- it's all about proper use of `memcache`!